# Does $ab \in Z(\mathbb{H})$ imply $ba \in Z(\mathbb{H})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the ring of real quaternions and $Z(\mathbb{H})$ be its center. Of course $Z(\mathbb{H})=\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $a+bi+cj+dk$, $x+yi+zj+wk \in \mathbb{H}$ such that $(a+bi+cj+dk)(x+yi+zj+wk) \in Z(\mathbb{H})$.

Does it imply $(x+yi+zj+wk)(a+bi+cj+dk) \in Z(\mathbb{H})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If either $a$ or $b$ is zero, so is $ba$.

If they are nonzero, and $t=ab$ is real, then $b=ta^{-1}$
and then $ba=ta^{-1}a=\cdots$.

Comment: +1: You definitely deserve the check. it took me a while to notice you had already done what I had in mind because the $t$ made it seem more complicated somehow. Sorry to have duplicated it... but I rather like my version, so I'll leave it up.

Answer (score 2):

If $ab$ is real, then it commutes with everything in $\mathbb H$.

Then $aba=a^2b$. Either $a=0$ and $ab=ba=0$, or else you can cancel $a$ from the left and get $ba=ab\in\mathbb R$.